# ScrolledText каждый раз создается заново при попытке вывода текста

Tags: python, tkinter

При вызове функции `vivod(res)` каждый раз создается новое текстовое поле. Пытался вытащить создание это поля из функции, в результате печатает только первый вызов. Надо, чтобы все вызовы выводились в один `ScrolledText`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()     # создание окна #
wid_r = root.winfo_screenwidth() - 20
hei_r = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(wid_r,hei_r))

res = [         # массив для проверки #
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [4,2,1,3]
]


def vivod(res):         # вывод в ScroledText # # !'ПРОБЛЕМКА ЗДЕСЬ'! #
    st= ScrolledText(root, width=50, height=10)
    st.insert(INSERT, '\n')
    for i in res:
        for j in i:
            st.insert(INSERT,j)
            st.insert(INSERT, '\t')
        st.insert(INSERT, '\n')
    st.configure(state='disabled')
    st.pack()
    


def gauss_decision(res):    # решение системы #
    k = 1 
    while k != len(res)-1:
        for i in range(1,len(res)):
            q = res[i][0]
            for j in range(len(res[0])):
                res[i][j] = res[i][j] - (q/res[0][0] * res[0][j])
                vivod(res)
                if ((i == len(res)-1) and (j == len(res[0])-1)):
                    for ii in range(k+1, len(res)):
                        w = res[ii][k]
                        for jj in range(k, len(res[0])):
                            res[ii][jj] = res[ii][jj] - (w/res[k][k] * res[k][jj])
                            vivod(res)
                    k += 1
                
def result(event):      # функции для вывода в ScrolledText по нажатию кнопки#
        vivod(res)
        gauss_decision(res)

button_result = Button(text = 'res')    # Кнопка #
button_result.bind('<Button-1>',result)
button_result.place(x=100, y=10, height=30,
                width=120)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Выносите создание и размещение поля `ScrolledText` наружу, туда где у вас кнопка создается, чтобы оно создавалось только один раз при старте, а не при каждом выводе.
2. В заблокированное текстовое поле нельзя ничего вывести, поэтому перед записью в него нужно его разблокировать, записать, потом заблокировать опять.

   Из-за того что у вас в коде стоит блокировка поля после вывода (но нет разблокировки до вывода), то срабатывает первый вывод, потом поле блокируется, и следующий вывод уже не срабатывает.

```
def vivod(res):
    st.configure(state='normal')
    st.insert(INSERT, '\n')
    for i in res:
        for j in i:
            st.insert(INSERT,j)
            st.insert(INSERT, '\t')
        st.insert(INSERT, '\n')
    st.configure(state='disabled')

...

button_result = Button(text = 'res')    # Кнопка #
button_result.bind('<Button-1>',result)
button_result.place(x=100, y=10, height=30,
                width=120)

st = ScrolledText(root, width=50, height=10, state='disabled')
st.pack()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!